# Laravel Microsoft Graph request how to solve Cannot use object of type?

Tags: laravel, api, graph

I try to do a graph request in my laravel project to connect Microsoft API. All works fine, but I don't find a way to get single data from my request.

```
   $info = $graph->createRequest("GET", "/groups/{id}/calendar/events?\$filter=start/dateTime ge '" . $todayDate . "T00:00' and end/dateTime lt '" . $todayDate . "T23:00'")

        ->addHeaders(array("Content-Type" => "application/json"))
        ->setReturnType(\Microsoft\Graph\Model\User::class)
        ->setTimeout("1000")
        ->execute();
```

Output is a large json with all information. If I just want to get $info[0]['attendees'];
I get error: Cannot use object of type Microsoft\Graph\Model\User as array in file
Why? And how to access? If I try load object like $info->attendees I got error: Trying to get property 'attendees' of non-object.

This is my output (not all) of `dd($info)` it includes attendees as array like "id"

```
array:10 [▼
  0 => Microsoft\Graph\Model\Event {#1532 ▼
    #_propDict: array:43 [▼
      "@odata.etag" => "{tag}""
      "id" => "{id}"
      "createdDateTime" => "2021-03-19T10:36:08.0812445Z"
      "lastModifiedDateTime" => "2021-03-19T10:36:11.9402917Z"
      "attendees" => array:1 [▼
                           0 => array:3 [▼
                                  "type" => "required"
                                  "status" => array:2 [▶]
                                  "emailAddress" => array:2 [▼
                                              "name" => "name"
                                              "address" => "mail"
                                  ]
                        ]
               ]
```

Comment: can you dd($info)

Comment: Take a look at my post again, I added first lines of output from dd($info) - Just first lines, because it's very long. One More thin, I changed Model User to Event, there is a function called getAttendees. But even not working.

Comment: there isn't any field for `attendees`

Comment: there is, I just put first rows of code. I added it now for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your array is returning an array of attendees, you have an extra level in your array. So to fetch the first attendees status, you need to use the following code:

Try this

```
       foreach($info as $item){
       foreach($item as $inf ){

       $a = $inf->status
    
        dd($a)
       } 
       }
```

Comment: ParseError: syntax error, unexpected '$inf' (T_VARIABLE) in file

Comment: Thanks again, I tried to decode json bevor, but get following error: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string array given.

Comment: Error: Cannot use object of type Microsoft\Graph\Model\User as array in file